# Show that a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a unique limit in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I need help with this problem:

> Show that a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a unique limit in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So, I tried using a theorem that says that $(a_k)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $a_k=(a_{k1},...,a_{ki})\ \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$, and $a=(a_1,...,a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $a_k\rightarrow a\iff a_{ki}\rightarrow a_i$ for each $i=1,...,n$.

I tried to show it by assuming that the statement is true when $n=1$ because my teacher said my could. Then If $(a_k)$ is a convergent series that means that $a_k\rightarrow a$, thus $a_{ki}\rightarrow a_i$. Since it is convergent and has a unique limit in $\mathbb{R}$, $a_{k1}\rightarrow a_1$ and $a_{k2}\rightarrow a_2\Rightarrow \ a_1=a_2$. Thus it works $\forall i=1,...,n$. Is my proof correct? If not, how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: How did you get that $a_1=a_2$?

Comment: Can you do the following: suppose $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ which converges, and suppose it converges to both $a$ and $b$. Then we have $$\Vert a-b\Vert\leq \Vert a-a_n\Vert+\Vert a_n-b\Vert\to 0\qquad n\to\infty$$ so we must have $\Vert a-b\Vert=0$.

Comment: @HarisGusic I get it from the definition. The convergence of $(a_k)$ is equivalent to the cconvergence of the coordinate sequences.

Comment: @Dave It follows from $\Vert a_k-a \Vert <\frac{ \epsilon}{2}$ and $\Vert a_k-b \Vert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$,thus $\Vert a-b \Vert$ $= \Vert a-a_k+a_k-b\Vert \leq \Vert a-a_k \Vert + \Vert a_k-b \Vert$ $<$ $\frac{ \epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$, so $\Vert a_k-a \Vert < \epsilon$, right? How do you get that $0$?

Comment: @davidllerenav well this is true for all $\varepsilon>0$. That is, for each $\varepsilon>0$, you can show that $\Vert a-b\Vert<\varepsilon$. This implies that $\Vert a-b\Vert=0$.

Comment: I see. It has to do with the fact tha t if $(a_k)$ is convergent, then $\lim_{k\to\infty} \Vert a_k-a \Vert = 0, right?

Comment: @Dave I have added a more detailed explanation in my answer. I hope you don't mind that I have included your proof in my answer.

Comment: @HarisGusic not at all; good answer (+1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one error.

$a_{k1} \to a_1$ and $a_{k2} \to a_2$ does not imply $a_1=a_2$, because $a_1$ and $a_2$ are different coordinates of the limit.

To make your proof complete, I would add:

> Since the limits of the sequences $a_{ki}$ (namely $a_i$) are unique, and since $a=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$, we have that the limit $a$ is unique as well. This follows from the fact that two ordered $n-$tuples are equal iff their respective coordinates are equal.

To elaborate more, consider the following.

Suppose for a contradiction that $b$ is another limit of the sequence $a_k$, and $b\neq a$. This means that $b_i \neq a_i$ for some $i$. But, as each coordinate of the limit is unique (based on the assumption your teacher permitted for $n=1$), having $b_i \neq a_i$ means that $b_i$ is not the limit of the sequence $a_{ki}$. This is a contradiction. Thus, we conclude that $b=a$.

---

Although this is a valid proof, the one that @Dave suggested is much more elegant:

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are two different limits of the sequence.

We have that $$0\leq\Vert a-b\Vert \leq \Vert a-a_k \Vert + \Vert a_k-b \Vert \to 0$$
By the squeeze theorem we have that $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \Vert a-b \Vert = 0$$
Because $a$ and $b$ are constants, this implies that $a=b$.

If @Dave decides to post this as his own answer, I will remove this alternate proof from my answer.

Comment: I understand the idea a little, can you please explain me why we have that the limit a is unique as well?

Comment: @davidllerenav I have updated my answer with more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The assistant teacher  show us that proof like I wrote it in the above coments, but since my teacher said that we can assume that the statement is true for $n=1$, it was quickier to do it the other way. Do you think that it is worth to write both proofs?

Comment: @davidllerenav Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did. Just one question, where did we show that each coordinate of the limit is unique?

Comment: @davidllerenav Ah, right. We didn't show that. It was the assumption your teacher gave (for $n=1$).

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. So every coordinate sequence has a unique limit, right? How do we arrive to the conclusion that $a$ is unique for $a_k$?

Comment: @davidllerenav There is only one (unique) "set" of numbers $a_i$, $i=1,...,n$ which represent the limits of the respective individual coordinates. Because $a$ is an $n-$tuple that is formed by these numbers, there is only one such $n-$tuple.